# В браузере хром пропали кнопки в инструментах разработчиков, как их вернуть?

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-devtools, инструменты-разработчика

Вот эти 4 кнопки были раньше, в новой версии их зачем то удалили, я не программист, научился баловаться с CSS можно сказать благодаря этим кнопкам, и они были очень полезны для меня и помагали мне создавать мои кастомные стили для разных сайтов для себя.. Спасите! Подскажите как вернуть эти кнопки???
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 0):

Все работает - и  Ctrl + Shift +I, и Дополнительные инструменты - Инструменты разработчика и F12
Сбросьте параметры браузера по умолчанию

Comment: Ничего не работает, я проверил в 3 браузерах на хромиуме включая сам хром...